# Longest string in an array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to get the maximum length of a string from an array of strings.

I wrote this code:

```
char a[100][100] = {"solol","a","1234567","123","1234"};
int max = -1;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(max<strlen(a[i]))
    max=strlen(a[i]);
cout<<max;
```

The output it gives is -1.
But when I initialize the value of max by 0 instead of 1, the code works fine. Why is it so?

Comment: Why `char[][]` and not `std::vector<std::string>>`? The latter would be super easy to just use `std::max_element` and is more C++ style.

Comment: The data type of `max` should be `size_t`.

Comment: @CoryKramer Just answer my question instead of suggesting me to use vectors. I know I can use vectors but why does this doesn't work?

Comment: Removed the c-Tag as title clearly states "C++"...

Comment: Are you getting a warning about comparing signed and unsigned types? Because -1 might be much larger than 500.

Comment: [Signed/unsigned comparisons](//stackoverflow.com/q/5416414)

Comment: @H.S. is right, it is likely due to `max<strlen(a[i])` comparison not working correctly since return of `strlen` is unsigned.

Comment: Well, you managed to fool me with the horrible indention. Maybe adopt a sane and safe coding style, by always using `{ }` and indention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Comment: @Lundin I purposely skip { } when I know beforehand that there will be a single statement in the block.

Comment: `std::max_element` can still be used, as demonstrated  [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f93a9d2ef6b3c27)

Comment: @MuktadirKhan Leaving the braces is not compatible with *almost* any coding conventions, and not with *really* any authoritative ones (such as MISRA). Long experience of thousands of coders, so many bugs when adding another instruction and forgetting the braces...

Comment: @MuktadirKhan Yeah, don't do that, it is bad practice.

Answer (score 6):

The function `strlen` returns an unsigned integral (i.e. `size_t`) so when you compare it to `max` which is signed, it gets promoted to unsigned and that `-1` turns to something like `0xffffffff` (the actual value depends on your architecture/compiler) which is larger than any of those strings.

Change `max` type to be `size_t` and never compare unsigned with signed integrals.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is the unsigned integer type.

From C++ Standard#4.6:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.15) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the
>   values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

The value of `max` is `-1` which represent the maximum value that an unsigned integer type can hold. In the expression `max<strlen(a[i])`, the value returned by `strlen` will be promoted to `unsigned int` and will be compared with the maximum value of the unsigned integer. Hence the condition `max<strlen(a[i])` will never `true` for the given input and the value of `max` will not change.

The longest string in the array of strings `a` is of length `7`. When you initialize the `max` with `0` or `1`, the expression `max<strlen(a[i])` evaluate to `true` for any string whose length is greater than the value of `max`. Hence you will get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

- [Implicit type conversion (coercion)](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/)

> When evaluating expressions, the compiler breaks each expression down into individual subexpressions. The arithmetic operators require their operands to be of the same type. To ensure this, the compiler uses the following rules:
>
> If an operand is an integer that is narrower than an int, it undergoes integral promotion (as described above) to int or unsigned int.
>   If the operands still do not match, then the compiler finds the highest priority operand and implicitly converts the other operand to match.
>   The priority of operands is as follows:
>
> ```
> long double (highest) 
> double
> float
> unsigned long long
> long long
> unsigned long
> long
> unsigned int
> int (lowest)
> ```

In your case on of operands has type int and another one type `size_t`, so `max` was promoted to type `size_t`, and bit representation of -1 is the biggest possible `size_t`.

You might also want to look in the following parts of the Standard [conv.prom],
 [conv.integral], [[conv.rank]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rank).

Comment: @Lundin thanks, for your comment. i would need to cite quite a lot from the Standard in this case. And Standard is not so easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` returns an unsigned int and when doing the comparison -1 gets promoted to a maximum value an unsigned can hold.

To fix the code, change the `max` definition to `unsigned int max = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you.

```
#include <algorithm>

  const size_t ARRAYSIZE = 100;
char stringArray[ARRAYSIZE][100] = {"solol","a","1234567","123","1234"};

auto longerString = std::max_element(stringArray, stringArray + ARRAYSIZE - 1, [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2){
      return strlen(s1) < strlen(s2);
    });

size_t maxSize = strlen(longerString[0]);
```

This works for me, returns the longest char array, just do a strlen over the "first element" and youre done. For your example, it returns 7.

Hope it helps.